# Class destructor with vector as member

Tags: class, inheritance, vector, destructor

Hello I have a Ball class.

```
 class Ball: public Pang::particle {
private:
    double radio;
    double rcolor, gcolor, bcolor; // Range 0.0-1.0 Color (given in RGB space)
```

Inherits from particle:

```
    class particle {

protected:

  double mass;
  vector3 position;
  vector3 velocity;

  vector3 acceleration;
  vector3 forceAccumulator;

  int state;
  double time_remaining;


public:

  particle();
  particle(const particle &rhs)
  {
    mass=rhs.mass;
    position = rhs.position;
    velocity = rhs.velocity;
    acceleration = rhs.acceleration;
    forceAccumulator = rhs.forceAccumulator;
    state = rhs.state;
    time_remaining = rhs.time_remaining;

  }
```

So my doubt is here i have a pangScenario class:

```
    namespace Pang {

class PangScenario {
    friend class ReflexAgentAI;
    friend class SimulationAI;
private:

    //Attributes are:Four planes, each one representing a plane ( scenario margin). el valor de position
    //Plane top;
    Plane bottomBorder;
    Plane leftBorder;
    Plane rightBorder;

    double limitPlane;

    //A ball positioned on it.
    //Ball scenarioBall;
    vector<Ball> playingBalls;
    character* characterPlayerOne;
    character* characterPlayerTwo;
    Ball* projectilePlayerOne;
    Ball* projectilePlayerTwo;
    double lastShotPlayerOne;
    double lastShotPlayerTwo;

    double lastDeadPlayerOne;
    double lastDeadPlayerTwo;

    int scorePlayerOne;
    int scorePlayerTwo;
    int livesPlayerOne;
    int livesPlayerTwo;
    int numberVictoriesPlayerOne;
    int numberVictoriesPlayerTwo;
    int numberTies;

    double widthGameField; // in meters
    double heightGameField; // in meters

    //friend ReflexAgentAI;

public:
    PangScenario();
    PangScenario(double width, double height);
    PangScenario(const PangScenario &rhs);
    virtual ~PangScenario()
    {
        if (projectilePlayerOne) delete projectilePlayerOne;
        if (projectilePlayerTwo) delete projectilePlayerTwo;
        if (characterPlayerOne) delete characterPlayerOne;
        if (characterPlayerTwo) delete characterPlayerTwo;
        //delete playingBalls;
    }
```

So as I use a vector in PangScenario, do I need to add a destructor to the vector playingBalls in the destructor of PangScenario? If so how can I do it?

Something like :

```
   for(int i=0 ; i < playingBalls.size(); ++i) {
  //pd = *it;
  playingBalls.erase(i); or delete playingBalls[i];
}
```

Perhaps a simple: `playingBalls.clear();` would be enough inside the destructor of `PangScenario`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it C++? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to destruct the `vector`. It is an object, not a pointer to an object, so you are not responsible for its cleanup. When the instance of the `PangScenario` class goes out of scope, all its member variables will be destroyed.

If you had a `vector<Ball> *` then you would need to be concerned with `delete`-ing any memory you allocated for it.

Finally, you do not need to `clear` the vector either. The `vector`'s own destructor will take care of cleaning itself up.

Comment: so the destructor is ok ? I dont need to do a delete playingBalls either as you can see its commented ...  Thanks

Comment: That is correct. You do NOT need to `delete playingBalls` or try to clean it up in any way whatsoever. In your destructor, you correctly delete the four objects that need deleting.